# Accessing arguments from a class passed down from the constructor into a method using rest

Tags: javascript, rest, class, for-loop, constructor

I am trying to pass each argument through the constructor into the method which in turn encrypt the values. But, the Method isn't reading the values in the arguments.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

```js
class Add {
    constructor(...words) {
        this.words = words;

    }

print(words){
    words = [words];
    let output = "$"
console.log(words)
    for(let word of words){
        output += word +"$"
    }
return output
}

    
}

var x = new Add("I", "Love","you");
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");

x.print()
z.print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled constructor and also if you assign something to `this` inside of constructor then you can also access that on `this` in other methods.

```js
class Add {
  constructor(...words) {
    this.words = words;
  }

  print() {
    let output = "$"
    for (let word of this.words) {
      output += word + "$"
    }
    return output
  }
}

var x = new Add("I", "Love", "you");
console.log(x.print())
```

Comment: I actually made an error in typing it here. Editing it Asap.